# Открытие новой вкладки по нажатию на иконку расширения в Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, json, html, javascript, chrome-extension

Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на иконку расширения в Google Chrome выскакивал не popup, а выполнялся скрипт (gen.js) и открывалась вкладка?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

в background.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="gen.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="background.js"></script>
```

в background.js:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(abc);
```

gen.js:

```
function abc() {
....
chrome.tabs.create({url:"http://mail.ru"});
}
```